# CheckBox validation in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, yii2

I've got a problem with validation for my $searchModel. I want to refreshing view of users accounts by checkbox which in my filter for searchModel. Now it is working but only when I push submittButton.

```
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'physiotherapist')->checkbox() ?>
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'office')->checkbox() ?>
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'withCallendar')->checkbox() ?>
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'verified')->checkbox() ?>



<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Filter'), ['class' => 'btn btn-search']) ?
<?php $form->end(); ?>
```

Any Ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Write some javascript to trigger the submit event of the form when changing the value of the checkboxes